# Weird bugs while working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I'm working on a specific page:

http://portfolio.jrstrauss.net/work/cg.html

and Chrome is doing a bizarre job of rendering the page. It renders perfectly in all the other browsers, Opera, Safari, Firefox, Camino, but Chrome does not give the same results.

I change nothing in the markup and refreshed, but now the layout is all jacked up. I was working with Chromium yesterday and started having the problem, but it was acting bizarre-- I would load the page and it would render fine every single time, but when I would refresh, it would completely change. Then tried it in Chrome and had no issues, so I passed it off as a Chromium bug. Now tonight it started doing the same thing in Chrome, even though it didn't before, so now I'm starting to wonder if there a problem with my markup. Though I see nothing. Does anyone else see a problem with my CSS or HTML?

If it looks good in Chrome on your computer, let me know via comment. I've taken a screen shot to show what it's supposed to look like and what it's doing weird in Chrome/ium.

Renders correctly:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXc0G.jpg

Renders incorrectly (only in Chrome and Chromium):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmIDF.jpg

Comment: Works fine for me in Chromium, Chrome and Rockmelt (based on chromium)

Answer (score 0):

It renders correctly in chrome for me, but it seems highly likely to be a problem with wrapping.  If I reduce the width of your `div.innerContentBox` from `800px` to `600px`, then it looks exactly like the problem you've shown.  As I said, I can't reproduce the problem, but it seems to have something to do with insufficient width.

Comment: I tried adjusting the with of innerContentBox to 100%, but still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: It could be that one of the enclosed `div`s is constraining the width also.  What version of chrome are you using?  I find it strange that no one else can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The newest version. I downloaded it last night and updated just now, just in case. The bug only appears when I refresh the page after loading it, so I think I might just ignore it and move on.